# Passing list from file to \foreach

Tags: macros, parameters

I'm trying to read lists of variable length from a configuration file to do something with if.

The lists are stored in the file as follows

```
list_1:x1, x2, x3
list_2:y1, y2
```

If I read the files with the **datatool** package, I can print them alright

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{:}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{config}{path_to_config_file}
\newcommand{\firstlist}{\DTLfetch{config}{key}{list_1}{value}}
\newcommand{\secondlist}{\DTLfetch{config}{key}{list_2}{value}}
...
\firstlist


\secondlist
```

This prints the following output

> x1, x2, x3
>
> y1, y2

I then try to pass them to the `\foreach` command from the **pgffor** package

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in { \firstlist}{%
    \foreach \y in {\secondlist}{%
        Value: \x \y
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

> Value: x1, x2, x3 y1, y2

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\DTLassignfirstmatch`, which can define macros expanding to the value. Note also that it should be `\foreach \x \in \firstlist` (no braces).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
list_1:x1, x2, x3
list_2:y1, y2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLsetseparator{:}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{config}{\jobname.dat}
\DTLassignfirstmatch{config}{key}{list_1}{\firstlist=value}
\DTLassignfirstmatch{config}{key}{list_2}{\secondlist=value}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in \firstlist {%
    \foreach \y in \secondlist {%
        Value: \x \y \par
    }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Usual *caveat*: I use `filecontents*` just for making the example self-contained.

Your `\firstlist` macro is essentially a set of (complex) instructions to *print* `x1, x2, x3` and cannot be used in the context of `\foreach`, which needs a macro directly expanding to a list.

Answer (score 1):

This uses `readarray` to input the config file and `listofitems` to parse it.  EDITED to provide for a header line in the config file, and to not presuppose a naming convention in the list names.  To accomplish this, I read the config file as a "raw" record array, discard the 1st line and compose a "cooked" config where each record now begins with the word `LISTNAME`.  This sets up for using `listofitems` to perform a 3-layer parsing of the `\cookedconfig` looking for `LISTNAME` to separate records, then `:` to separate listname from list data, and finally `,` to separate the components of the list data.

From there, the loops, using both `\foreach` and `\foreachitem` write themselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents,pgffor,lmodern}
\begin{filecontents*}{config}
This is a header row
list A:x1, x2, x3
lstB  :y1, y2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\readrecordarray{config}\rawconfig
\def\cookedconfig{}
\makeatletter
\foreach\row in{2,...,\numexpr\rawconfigROWS-1}{%
  \g@addto@macro\cookedconfig{LISTNAME}%
  \arraytomacro\rawconfig[\row]\thisrow%
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\cookedconfig\expandafter{\thisrow}%
}
\makeatother
\ignoreemptyitems
\setsepchar{LISTNAME/:/,}
\readlist*\myconfig{\cookedconfig}

The list names are:\par
 \foreach\row in {1,...,\listlen\myconfig[]}{%
 \texttt{\myconfig[\row,1]}, consisting of 
 \foreachitem\x\in\myconfig[\row,2]{%
   \ifnum\xcnt=1\else, \fi\texttt{\x}}
 \par
}

The desired loop of the OP is 

\foreachitem\x\in\myconfig[1,2]{%
  \foreachitem\y\in\myconfig[2,2]{%
    Value \texttt{\x{} \y}\par
}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can even use the "trick" of getting `\readdef` to insert the characters `LISTNAME` between each record, thus saving a little bit of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray,filecontents,pgffor,lmodern}
\begin{filecontents*}{config}
This is a header row
list A:x1, x2, x3
lstB  :y1, y2
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand\cookconfig[1]{\expandafter\cookconfigaux#1\endcookconfig}
\def\cookconfigaux#1LISTNAME#2\endcookconfig{\gdef\cookedconfig{LISTNAME#2}}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{LISTNAME}
\readdef{config}\rawconfig
\cookconfig{\rawconfig}
\setsepchar{LISTNAME/:/,}
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist*\myconfig{\cookedconfig}

The list names are:\par
 \foreach\row in {1,...,\listlen\myconfig[]}{%
 \texttt{\myconfig[\row,1]}, consisting of 
 \foreachitem\x\in\myconfig[\row,2]{%
   \ifnum\xcnt=1\else, \fi\texttt{\x}}
 \par
}
The desired loop of the OP is 

\foreachitem\x\in\myconfig[1,2]{%
  \foreachitem\y\in\myconfig[2,2]{%
    Value \texttt{\x{} \y}\par
}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I seem to have run into a few problems with your package. Is it possible to use **\n** as a separator? I ask this because the real list names do not always contain the string _list_, and would ideally like to get a line first, then the lists.

Additionally, I have tried using \readarray by **:**, then split the second column by **,**, but cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: @rsotomayorf Revised to hopefully meet your needs.