# Automate data input

Tags: automation, database

I have a tex body which looks something like

> This week we have added 5600 vaccines in the inventory which is a 8.5% increase compared to last week.

Now, these number, 5600 and 8.5% are updated every week based on a table that updates every week automatically.

The table is generated in tableau and connected to SQL server , so the same table updates every week based automatically. I want to reflect the changes in the line automatically. I can feed the table as a reference or something but want the test to extract the data and update itself.
Currently I go back to the table and manually update each data based on the table in the text.

Is there a way to do that in latex? The table can be a csv. The table updates itself, but the text does not.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes advantage of the fact that TeX lengths are stored as integers in machine units and that I can assign those lengths into count registers and vice versa.

The multiplier of 1000 in the MWE is what gives me 3 significant digits from my integer divide.  Those three digits, in percent form, are `xx.x%`.

I use `readarray` to grab the data from a file, and `listofitems` to parse it into an array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.txt}
458
589
743
799
853
942
925
1000
2345
\end{filecontents*}
\newcount\currcount
\newcount\lastcount
\newlength\currlen
\def\fmtvalue#1#2\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax.#1\%\else#1\fmtvalue#2\relax\fi}
\def\weeklyincrease[#1]{\csname weeklyincrease[#1]\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{mydata.txt}\datadef
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist\datarray{\datadef}
\noindent\makebox[1in][r]{Vaxx inventory}\makebox[1in][r]{Increase}\par\noindent
\foreachitem\z\in\datarray[]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1in][r]{\z}%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\makebox[1in][r]{---~~~}\relax\else
    \lastcount=0\datarray[\zcnt-1]\relax
    \currcount=0\z\relax
    \currlen=1000\currcount\relax
    \divide\currlen by \lastcount\relax
    \currcount=\currlen\relax
    \advance\currcount by -1000\relax
    \expandafter\edef\csname weeklyincrease[\zcnt]\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\fmtvalue\the\currcount\relax}%
    \makebox[1in][r]{\weeklyincrease[\zcnt]}%
  \fi
  \par\noindent
}

In week 5, the vax inventory was \datarray[5], with a weekly
  increase of \weeklyincrease[5].
  
For week 7, the comparable numbers were \datarray[7] and
  \weeklyincrease[7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want the table output, just comment out the `\makebox` macros.

---

For those sticklers that insist on proper rounding, instead of truncation, one must obtain an extra significant digit (thus the 10000 multipliers) and then evaluate that for determining whether or not to bump the prior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.txt}
458
589
743
799
853
942
925
1000
2345
\end{filecontents*}
\newcount\currcount
\newcount\lastcount
\newlength\currlen
\def\fmtvalue#1#2#3\relax{\ifx\relax#3\relax.%
  \ifnum#2>4\relax\the\numexpr#1+1\relax\else#1\fi\%\else
  #1\fmtvalue#2#3\relax\fi}
\def\weeklyincrease[#1]{\csname weeklyincrease[#1]\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{mydata.txt}\datadef
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist\datarray{\datadef}
\noindent\makebox[1in][r]{Vaxx inventory}\makebox[1in][r]{Increase}\par\noindent
\foreachitem\z\in\datarray[]{%
  \noindent\makebox[1in][r]{\z}%
  \ifnum\zcnt=1\makebox[1in][r]{---~~~}\relax\else
    \lastcount=0\datarray[\zcnt-1]\relax
    \currcount=0\z\relax
    \currlen=10000\currcount\relax
    \divide\currlen by \lastcount\relax
    \currcount=\currlen\relax
    \advance\currcount by -10000\relax
    \expandafter\edef\csname weeklyincrease[\zcnt]\endcsname{%
      \expandafter\fmtvalue\the\currcount\relax}%
    \makebox[1in][r]{\weeklyincrease[\zcnt]}%
  \fi
  \par\noindent
}

In week 5, the vax inventory was \datarray[5], with a weekly
  increase of \weeklyincrease[5].
  
For week 7, the comparable numbers were \datarray[7] and
  \weeklyincrease[7]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is beautiful. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is beautiful and very advanced. So if I have a table with many 5 columns, [a],[b],[c],[d],[e] how do you propose I include that in this system, in place of weekly index and data array.

Comment: @R.Islam You should have a look at the `listofitems` documentation, https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems, which should guide you.  An answer like this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474397/populate-information-from-a-csv-file-into-a-latex-document-specifically-into-th/474441#474441, shows how to read multi-column data into a 2-D array.  Then, to reference the data, something like `\datarray[2]` grabs the whole 2nd row, whereas `\datarray[2,3]` grabs the 3rd column from the 2nd row. Finally, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399938/passing-list-from-file-to-foreach/399943#399943

Comment: @R.Islam ...to understand how to set up `\foreachitem` loops on specific columns within the rows of data.

Comment: Thank you so much.....